# Backup mysql database through ssh using php

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I'm trying to backup mysql database through SSH using PHP.
I have made the ssh connection through ssh but I'm not making any progress 
with the database backup.
This is my code :

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

if(!($con = ssh2_connect("server.hosting.com", 22))){
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {

    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "user", "password")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        // allright, we're in!
        echo "okay: logged in...\n";




        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'echo "mysqldump -u userdb -p pass

dbname tablename > mydb_tab.sql"|mysql'))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
            // collect returning data from command
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when running this script??

Comment: your exec call is useless. `mysql` expects **SQL** as input, and you're feeing it some random text that happens to be a valid shell command. you DON'T need `mysql` for a dump. all it should be is `mysqldump ... > dump.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is not correct, it should read like this:

```
mysqldump -h server –uuserdb  -ppass dbname > mydb_tab.sql
```

Comment: This command generates the mydb_tab.sql but there is nothing inside it .

Comment: Im trying this one now but still nothing :( 

`<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('server.hosting.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection,'user', 'pass');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'mysqldump -h server.hosting.com -uuserdb -ppass

dbname > mydb_tab.sql');
?>`

Comment: Go on ur sever and try it directly there before doing it trhough code look for errrors